# Can I use a regular ball-bearing drawer slidse on their side?

Tags: drawers, shelf, cupboard

I'm wanting to create a sliding shelf by essentially adding drawer slides on top of an existing shelf and a piece of wood on  top of that:

[image]

My question is... Are regular ball bearing slides bought from the DIY shop strong enough to be used in a flat manner like this?

**They weight I will be supporting is approximately 12kg**

I have seen some slides online that quote a supported capacity of 40kg, but I am aware this is meant to be supported vertically and not flat.

If this is not the best idea, would there be anything more suitable?

Comment: Do not think regular drawer slides would work well, the weight would be on top of them, instead of them holding from the side.  Do think there are shelf slides made for what you want, but might hard to find.  Might try bottom mount.

Comment: Make an answer out of that, @AloysiusDefenestrate!

Answer (score 3):

You want “center mount” or “undermount” drawer slides. Ordinary ones probably won’t work.

For example: [center mount slide](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/slides/undermount/50509-center-mount-slides?item=02K4014&utm_source=free_google_shopping&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=shopping_feed&gclid=CjwKCAjw9suYBhBIEiwA7iMhNDPLSmkgpNJbLSSUDe2aawvKSHNJT3er_ghGZvywyx7kqeZFifzAoRoC830QAvD_BwE).

(Not, strictly speaking, an endorsement of this item, though I don’t think I’ve ever been disappointed by a Lee Valley purchase.)